# How to compare current time only without date to a given time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am writing javascript code to show a shop open or close based on time he input.
I have a array of opening and closing time of a week.
And i want to check that the current time is between opening time range or not.
I just converted string of time like "08:30" to hours and minutes.

```
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){                               //line 1
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){                           //line 2
        var hr = timing[i][j].substring(0, 2);      //line 3
        var mi = timing[i][j].substring(3, 5);      //line 4
        alert(hr+" "+mi);                            //line 5
    }                                                //line 6
}   
                                             //line 7
```

but now i want insert these hours and minutes into that array
something like

```
timing[i][j] = new Date(hr, mi); //in place of line 5
```

but i know its incorrect format.
date function has parameters like

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

but i don't have any year, day or hours.
if it possible to store only hours and minutes then please help me to explain how current time(hr:mi) can be compared to given time(hr;mi).

Comment: Instead of trying to set a date variable with "no date", why not make sure that `date(hr, mi)` always returns the specified time of today's date? That way, you can compare current time with today's operating hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do

```
// to save 
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(hr);
d.setMinutes(mi);

//to compare with the current time
var d2 = new Date();
console.log(d2 - d);
```

Comment: You can do `d.setHours(hr, mi, 0, 0)` to set all the time values in one go. ;-)